# How to set the height in the code of the UITextView created with Xcode storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uitextview

I can not set the height while running of the UITextView object in Xcode for iPhone (Version 4.6 (4H127).
I have used MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard to create the UITextView.

I have tried this, which makes no effect:

```
UITextView *textMultiLine1;
[textMultiLine1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];
```

Thanks for answering, I am a very beginner in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an Outlet in you header file:

```
IBOutlet UITextView *textMultiLine1;
```

Then you need to connect it in the StoryBoard:

[image]

Then you must set it's frame:

```
textMultiline1.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, width, height);
```

Or, if you want to change only it's height:

```
float newHeight = 200.0;

CGRect textViewFrame = textMultiline1.frame;
textMultiline1.frame = CGRectMake(textViewFrame.origin.x, textViewFrame.origin.y, textViewFrame.size.width, newHeight);
```

Setting the content size will only change the inner TextView area, resulting in a longer (or shorter, depending on the values you set) scroll

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer.

Comment: I get (CGRect) origin=(x=0,y=0) size=(width=0, height=0) when I use your example. In my header file I can only write like this: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textMultiLine1;

Comment: Are you sure you have connected the outlet to the TextView in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes it is connected. How can I send you a screen shote etc?

Comment: You can upload it to http://imgur.com and send me the URL. If you like , you can send me your code so I can take a better look at it. Send me an URL as well.

Comment: I have found the problem, but not the solution. When I do the set size change later, when the view is loaded (e.g. with a button), then it works. How can I say the view to be drawn on the display at start, like "doevents" in visual basic?

Comment: All subviews of you UIViewController main view are already loaded when `- (void) viewDidLoad;` is called. When you have a view in Interface Builder, it's automatically allocated and all it's properties are inherited from whatever you've set in IB. Make sure you are not allocating (`textMultiLine1 = [[UITextView alloc] init]`) it again.

Comment: I have a single view application and unfortunately the view is not loaded after "viewDidLoad". So I introduced a timer, which looks if the height is "0" and when is no more "0" then the timer is stopped. Sorry I can not loose more time in this detail. Thanks very much for your support.

Comment: I have found the problem. The "UITextView" object was set to "Use Autolayout" in story board.

Comment: So you just turned it off?

Comment: Yes, and everything worked well. The "Autolayout" did always overwrite my settings.